# RadListView Telerik UI "Cannot read property 'setLayoutParams' of undefined"

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

while trying to use RadListView from TelerikUI, I faced an error I cannot get a hang on. According to the angular samples, I

imported the module in my submodule.ts file

```
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/angular";
```

and

```
@NgModule({


 imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptI18nModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    subRouting,
    NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ListPageComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class SubModule {}
```

created the data object definition in the ListPageComponent

```
class DataItem {
    constructor(public id: string, public type: string) { }
}
```

and wrote my component class

```
@Component({
    selector: "list",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "list.page.html",
    styleUrls: ["list.page.css"]
})
export class ListPageComponent implements OnInit {

    public _dataItems: DataItem[] = [
        {id: "1", type: "A"},
        {id: "2", type: "A"},
        {id: "3", type: "A"}
    ];
    get dataItems(): ObservableArray<DataItem> {
        return new ObservableArray(this._dataItems);
    }


    constructor(
        private _pageRoute: PageRoute,
        private _routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
        private _page: Page
    ){
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }        
}
```

finally, trying to render as defined with

```
<GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
    <RadListView [items]="dataItems" col="0" row="1">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <GridLayout columns="auto" rows="auto">
                <Label class="descriptionLabel" [text]="item.type" col="0" row="0"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>        
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

The example works with the basic listview, but switching to the RadListView throws

```
An uncaught Exception occured on "main" thread. com.tns.NativeScriptException:
Calling js method onCreateViewHolder failed

Type Error: Cannot read property 'setLayoutParams' of undefined File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/listview.js, line: 102 column: 42

StackTrace:
Frame: function:'ListViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder', file"file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/listview.js, line: 102 column: 43

at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative (Native Method) [...]
```

on my android emulator (no chance to test on ios yet)

It seems, I'm doing a basic thing wrong with RadListView, although I kept fully aligned with the nativescript-ui-samples for angular app.

My package.json excerpt

```
"nativescript": {
        "id": "org.nativescript.myapp",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "3.1.1"
        },
        "tns-ios": {
            "version": "3.1.0"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~4.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~4.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~4.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~4.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~4.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "~4.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~4.2.0",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "nativescript-angular": "~4.2.0",
        "nativescript-gif": "^2.0.0",
        "nativescript-i18n": "^0.2.2",
        "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^3.1.0",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "~5.4.2",
        "tns-core-modules": "~3.1.1",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
    },
```

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update everything to the latest version `tns plugin update`. also update the android and ios versions to 3.2.0

Comment: Found a new post (only some hours ago) on github accordingly:

https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/293

Comment: This answer also helped me with the same issue I am having working with vanilla NS.